# Primefaces dataTable reRender column is not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using Primefaces 5.1 in my page I use dataTable inside another dataTable.In add button press add new bean for salList and check salList not null to rendered header column.But sal column not rendered.

```
<p:dataTable id="mainTable" value="#{employee.employeeList}" var="emp" ..>

<p:columnGroup type="header">
<p:row >
<p:column headerText="Name"/>
</p:column headerText="value" **rendered="#{emp.salList ne null and not empty emp.salList}**/> 
....
<p:column>
<f:facet name="header"><p:commandButton value="add button" action="#{employee.addButton}" update="mainTable"/>
</f:facet>
</p:column>

</p:row>
</p:columnGroup>

<p:column>
<p:dataTable value="#{emp.salList}" var="sp">
<p:column></p:column>
..
</p:dataTable>
</p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

My doubt is when I press add button to add new list salList bean  and it add new bean and show component in inside dataTable.But in header column salary column is not rendered i.e header column not updated it will not rendered the specify header column.

Comment: please correct your sentences. `My doubt is when I press add button to add new list salList bean and it create new list and show component in inside dataTable` doesnt make sense for example.

Comment: 'not working' is not usefull. What does the response look like? Just the plain table again? Full page refresh? etc... investigate more